# JQuery Confirm DropDown Selection (Cancel Not Working)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JQuery that displays

1. A confirmation window when "ON" is selected and
2. Displays a hidden submit button.

Everything is working fine EXCEPT, when I click cancel on the confirmation window it still proceeds to populate the selection box with "ON" and the submit button is shown. Any Suggestions?

CODE:

```
$( ".BUTTON" ).prop( "disabled", true );

$(function() {
    $('select[name="SomeName"]').on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'ValueOn'){ 
            if (confirm('Are You Sure You Want to Turn it On?')); 
            $(".BUTTON").prop('disabled', false).val('');
            return;
        } else {
            $(".BUTTON").prop('disabled', true).val('');
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: And did you notice that the code highlighting goes weird after that missed quote on your last `.BUTTON` selector? That's not missing in your running code too, is it?

Comment: It's not missing in running code @linuxdisciple (but good spot) will update.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to put your button's disabling process inside the if statement but not after it. So your code would look like following.

```
$( ".BUTTON" ).prop( "disabled", true );

$(function() {
    $('select[name="SomeName"]').on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'ValueOn'){ 
            if (confirm('Are You Sure You Want to Turn it On?')){ 
                $(".BUTTON").prop('disabled', false).val('');
            }
            else{
                $(".BUTTON").prop('disabled', true).val('');
            }
            return;
        } 
        else {
            $(".BUTTON").prop('disabled', true).val('');
            return;
        }
    });
});
```